# Bring the DevDays love to the forsaken continent/island Australia

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2009

In response to Joel trying to convince Jeff to skip over to Australia in Feb.
I would like to extend the warmest welcome to Papa Smurf and Dinosaur Joel!

Us Australians felt extremely left out when all the Dev Days fun was being had in the other parts of the world and would **love** to see one in our somewhat forsaken part of the planet.

If you come, we'll forgive you for [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/):

[image: Ghost of a spammer?]

Comment: Aww... I was hoping for a 2Pac photo.

Comment: @Shog9: Fixed that for ya.

Comment: Smurfsnorting your are the most awesome smurf ever !

Comment: Thanks! Heh -- next time I change my name, that comment will **so** not make sense.

Comment: -1 for Australia. I have had it up to here with that stupid continent.

Comment: Me too, I think its time to move to NZ, at least they have the flight of the conchords, what do we have? olivia newton-john and savage garden. geez we suck.

Comment: Hahaha, that pic is awesome waffles!

Comment: :D :D :D :D :D :D

Comment: Australia developers *desperately* need something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's next?  Please come to South Africa! Russia!

What about Austria? Egypt? Poland? or stackoverflowers in India?

Don't worry, I am sure Australia is somewhere on their list. ;)

I agree though, more dev days are needed in the areas where SO traffic is most common. At the rate SO is growing, this could become a reality soon. So tell your friends!

Comment: Its in direct response to the podcast ... they were talking about making it happen ... so im trying to get some support for it. besides Australia is the most neglected of all the geos when it came to devdays having quite a big percentage of SO users.

Comment: @waffles: You need some more pics containing famous Australians. ;) And I agree, more dev days are needed in the areas where SO traffic is most common.

Comment: I could always add a picture of melvin gibson I guess :p

Comment: They've already been to Canada: http://stackoverflow.carsonified.com/events/toronto/

Comment: i fixed that image just for you troggy

Comment: @Kyle: Thank you, I swear I thought they went at least somewhere in Canada, but couldn't remember exactly where. My bad, canadians got some love.

Answer (score 13):

I think it is important to note that, in addition to the beautiful summer weather we have in February, it is also *Rainbows and Unicorns Season* in Sydney.

Something everyone should see before they die.

[image]

With pony rides, kangaroo steaks and a rabid Australian developer community, this is just one more reason to bring Devdays to Sydney.

Comment: *Disclaimer: You have to bring your own acid if you indeed want to see the unicorns. Seeing rainbows, on the other hand, does not require chemical enhancement.

Comment: http://imgur.com/RX4JC.jpg

Comment: ... why is there a canadian flag ontop of the bridge? I'm looking out my window right now and I clearly see the Australian and NSW flags...

Comment: @Farseeker I have no idea, it must have been a thing.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so what do we need in order to make this happen? I have zero conference organisation experience, virtually no money and a tiny bit of time. What can I do to help make this happen.

Now that I've written that I realised the answer to that would be finding people that have those three things.

Seriously, can we get this off the ground?

Answer (score 1):

I would welcome them, but Jeff has to stop the Koala and Kangaroo hate! At least try a Kangaroo steak first! Maybe we could invite the 2 programmers from New Zealand over too? :)

Comment: If he goes to NZ, he could try a kiwiburger. Small flightless birds ... it tastes like chicken.

Comment: I never liked the Kiwi... Although, It would make a great photo op to see Joel and Jeff doing the Haka :)

Comment: Kangaroo steak is an experience...

Comment: Both if cooked correct and if cooked badly. :)