# Meta Image Contest

Tags: discussion, meta, waffles, contest

On Meta, we have many 'meta' memes. Unicorns, waffles, etc. We even have an entire sub-category of memes specifically designed for images, such as free-hand circles and lens flares.

Well, it is times to put both your artistic skills, along with your meme knowledge to action!

### I am offering a 550 reputation bounty to whoever can create the most meta image.

## Contest has ended.

Comment: I salute you sir!

Comment: Can the image be (primarily) a photograph, if it is of our own making? (This sounds like a most excellent challenge for my 365 photos thing ... )

Comment: Not Community Wiki?

Comment: Silly people.  CW is for wiki questions, especially on meta.  There's little (no?) reason to make the question and answers editable by people with 100 rep - these are submissions to a contest.

Comment: Can one take a photograph, not screenshot, of ASCII art?

Comment: Nice.  You'll easily recoup the 550 rep.

Comment: @waiwai I added a couple rules to mitigate those loopholes.

Comment: can i use hand-drawn ascii art?

Comment: Can I use macaroni pictures that look like ascii art?

Comment: @Jon: doesn't stop you from doing to, though.

Comment: Can I Create ASCII Art, print it on a piece of paper, put in on a Wooden Table, take a digital photograph of it, print out the digital photograph onto paper and then scan it in?

Comment: @Michael: No, but you can carve ASCII directly into the table and ship it to the OP's house where he will take a photograph of it, which he will then upload to his computer and take a screenshot of, and then post as an answer.

Comment: I can't do art at work. : ( Contest is open until bounty-deployment, right?

Comment: @rlb: you think that I did [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47324/meta-image-contest/47337#47337) at work? Pffft! At work I can't have nice things, like KDE. I have to settle for GNOME! Can you imagine!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Still work in progress; I have a few more ideas for later. Click for full-size version.

[image: balpha work of art]

Comment: This gets my vote because the memes are subtle - I like it!

Comment: It took me a minute or two to get "data dump" and I still don't undertand the meaning of the VW.

Comment: @Kyle: it's a feature!

Comment: @Kyle: Art shouldn't have to be explained :) But take a look at the copyright notice on the poster.

Comment: ah, the bug is "by design" :)

Comment: @balpha: damn! you took the time to project the unicorn's shadow.

Comment: Who's the face in the mountain?

Comment: @SLaks: Jon Skeet. You are in big trouble for not recognizing him...

Comment: I'm disappointed that Iceland is not spewing volcanic ash in the form of a dessicated LOLcat.

Comment: Not enough Iceland and jQuery.

Comment: @Ólafur Waage: Are you telling me the picture was not taken in (on?) Iceland? [The photographer sure says so](http://www.sxc.hu/photo/25974).

Comment: I never said that, I said that it does not have enough. It needs more!

Comment: @Ólafur Waage: Yeah, umm, whatever. No more Iceland for you. You've got seven Fridays per week already, don't start being greedy.

Comment: I kinda like this one. Well thought out!

Comment: I like how the calendar shows 6-8 weeks, but there's still something syrupy missing.

Comment: @gnovices-exchange: Even *if* I can find a good idea to include waffles -- there'll definitely be no syrup. Putting syrup onto waffles is just wrong. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/wmd-editor-bug-german-keyboard-layout-creates-blockquote-section/44134#44134) for more info.

Comment: Congratulations on the 800 rep this post has gotten you.

Comment: @Chacha102: I can't believe you didn't pick me as the winner! That is so not fair. You did not make the rules clear enough. ;-)

Comment: We detected an invalid link in your post, please correct it. (this message will be automatically removed when the link is fixed)

Comment: Anyone have a mirror 6 years later?

Comment: @JAL I know you asked a year ago, but there ^ you go :)

Answer (score 39):

It's not filled with memes, but *one day* we might need meta.meta.meta.meta.meta.stackoverflow.com!

[image: http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/4945/metaxj.jpg]

Comment: If you can add to every recursion one more `meta.` to `meta.meta.stackoverflow.com`...

Comment: Almost felt like I couldn't upvote, to not change the overall result...

Comment: Allow me to help you there :)

Comment: We already need meta.meta.meta.meta.meta.stackoverflow.com !!

Comment: Can't upvote twice, but I have a black up-arrow. ;-)

Comment: I like how the score has gone down since the time you took the screenshots

Comment: @ColeJohnson: It’s fake :)

Answer (score 25):

[image: Not programming related]

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but as someone from ServerFault I don't get this one?

Comment: @Farseeker: it's referring to an old SO question about boats, which would have been closed in an instant nowadays: archived at http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/

Comment: @Ether that link is gone

Answer (score 24):

I read the rules like 5 times, but I had a hard time understanding them. I really hope this doesn't break any of them. :)

[image]

Comment: Your logic is impeccable. And by impeccable, I MEAN COMPLETELY PECCABLE!!! /Dr. Doofenshmirtz reference

Comment: @waiwai933: **Dr. Doofenshmirtz** *(upon seeing Perry)* "Perry the Platypus, what an unexpected surprise! And by unexpected, I really mean unexpected--what are you doing here? This is my week off."

Comment: -1 Breaks the rules.

Comment: @George: I think you may have missed my point.

Comment: @Dexter: No, **you** missed the point. See the rules.

Comment: @George: I'm sorry George it seems you have missed my point again, that's my fault, I should have been more clear. **MY POINT WAS TO BREAK THE RULES!!!!**

Comment: @Dexter: Dishonest cheater! :) On a more serious note, I did understand what you were saying all along - I just wanted it in writing so that we could sue you.

Comment: I flagged your post.

Comment: @George: You can sue people on {M}SOFU? Do you sue for rep? If this is true, I have a score to settle with Jon Skeet for about, oh 160K rep. ;-)

Comment: -1.  not for breaking the rules; for corrupting the hallowed art of ASCII art to depict *a unicorn*.  where'd i leave my shotgun?

Comment: @quack: Wait...are you saying that a unicorn isn't worthy of being depicted in ASCII art?

Comment: @dexter: yes.  yes, i am.

Comment: Ahhh - the ultimate meta meme.  Breaking the rules.  Now you must be banned.

Comment: @tvanfosson: I'll be in good company: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5640/

Comment: **When will this flagged post get removed???**

Comment: @George: It's probably less likely to get removed, then it would be for you to get banned for flagging post for stupid reasons.

Comment: LOL @George thinking that a post is going to get removed just because he flagged it.

Comment: Ya... I'm kidding but... you never know when you'll get sympathy from others.

Comment: PHP…………………… >:(

Answer (score 21):

First draft of my self portrait. I gotta stop procrastinating with this stuff, [Rainbows and Unicorns Season](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31942/bring-the-devdays-love-to-the-forsaken-continent-island-australia/32845#32845) is coming up.

[image]

Comment: There are letters on that screen!!!! That has to count as ASCII Art!

Comment: "a form of art that uses only ASCII characters" - Sadly mine doesn't qualify as that squiggle next to the other squiggle is actually the unicode snowman ☃ ... If only I had stuck to ASCII characters.

Comment: How does the Unicorn push `Ctrl+Alt+Del`? Think about it...

Comment: @george-edison I would thank you to not ridicule the very real problems involved with hooves and software development.

Comment: @NathanOsman If there are any keys between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> (mine has a winDOS key), remove them :)

Answer (score 19):

This was based upon the first revision of this question.

[Booyah http://www.41085.org/myfuckinghandhurts.png](http://www.41085.org/myfuckinghandhurts.png)

Comment: It has a free-hand circle AND is un-readable.

Comment: See if you can play spot-the-differences too

Comment: I see I have a `status-by-design` tags now :)

Comment: His rep doesn't match nor does his acceptance rate.

Comment: Well, his rep and acceptance were correct at time of printing (53% and 7,114)

Comment: @Dexter I imagine the rep was due to the fact that I got 6-7 upvotes since the original version of the question.

Comment: @Chacha102: Ah your right...but that still doesn't explain the acceptance rate.

Comment: Acceptance rate is still 53% - you just can't see it in the image. I'll hyperlink it to the full-sized version

Comment: @Farseeker: OK I guess I see that now. You also have very sloppy 3's (as if I'm the best person to be critiquing you (my 6's and G's are awful)).

Comment: By the end of that image, my hand was going to fall off. And I have a crappy Dell mouse at this workstation, so quality is... poor at the best of times

Comment: Oh, and my handwriting in real life isn't much better. I never even got my "pen license" in Grade 4

Comment: @Farseeker: So I guess that explains the filename? ;-)

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 15):

http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/5893/metad.png

Comment: I was wondering if anyone would go and dig up that castle and go to all the effort of re-enabling the `kbd` styles

Comment: P.S. now we all know your email address *clickty click* Hmm, json, I didn't know you liked horses that much!

Comment: @Farseeker: look at my profile. It's there in the open.
I don't like horses. It's an unicorn rode by Robocop. Who doesn't like that? And if the image is supposed to be "Meta", it has to habe at least a unicorn.

Comment: I don't see any lasers in this one.

Comment: @Welbog: does the UFO's tractor beam count?

Comment: -1 for taking the screenshot on KDE. I prefer gnome.

Comment: @George: would you have downvoted if I had been using awesome, Enlightenment or XFCE?

Comment: @json: I would have upvoted XFCE.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 14):

[image: "It's a Skeet Friday in Iceland"]

Comment: Fastest gun in the west fail. : /

Comment: My only question is what the crap is that background!?

Comment: @Earlz Iceland!

Comment: Somewhere cold, in a land far far away, Jon Skeet is wishing he had his bath robe.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Comment: For those interested, it's the Eldfell volcano eruption in 1973 on an island very close to Eyjafjallajökull called Heimaey.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lIMpk5-2Oc

Comment: @Ólafur: Yeah, I couldn't find a picture of the Eyjarjarbinks volcano erupting with houses in the foreground, so I had to settle for Eldfell. ;)

Comment: Eyjafjallajökull is so far away from a town that you cant see the eruption, only smoke.

Comment: @Ólafur: How *do* you pronounce Eyjafjallajökull, anyway? I'm guessing that j is pronounced like an English y, but what about that "yj" bit?

Comment: The main trick is the double l. Since it's a clicking sound. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Eyjafjallaj%C3%B6kull-bjarmason.ogg

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Comment: Obvious waffle photoshop fail.

Answer (score 6):

Might need more rainbow sparkles.

[image]

Comment: Those ragged edges aren't nice... Here's a [better version of your unicorn](http://unicorn.xn---wie-geek-p9a.de/0bf5f81f9852861944d7306696884226.png).

Comment: Thanks, was wondering could you generate it with the background.

Comment: It's a unicorn, Charlie!