# Help Choose the Speakers and Talks for Dev Days 2011 [Australia]

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2011

We need your help to pick what speakers and talks you want to hear at [Dev Days 2011](http://devdays.stackoverflow.com)!  We're looking for 3-4 people (for each city) to join our Curriculum Committees - this group will be responsible for selecting the topics being covered and the speakers giving those talks.

This role has a lot of responsibility (since you'll be picking all the content for Dev Days).  Ideal members should be heavily involved in the SO community, know the topics that people will find interesting, and have the time over the next month to put in at least 5 hours a week discussing options with your fellow committee members.  Also, please only nominate yourself for the committee in the city that you are planning on attending Dev Days.

So, if you're interested in joining the curriculum committee, please submit your name as an answer below, along with a couple of sentences about why you'll be a strong addition to the team.  You can also vote up people who you think would be good (the top 4 vote-getters aren't guaranteed to be the ones we select, but it will certainly weigh heavily in our decision).

Look forward to seeing you all at Dev Days 2011!

Comment: I'd be interested in being a committee member, but I'm not sure I know enough different speakers to be able to contribute "usefully".

Comment: Thanks SO for offering a DevDay in Australia. /me wipes a tear away (no sarcasm, real <3 )

Answer (score 16):

I would like to nominate myself.

I can not promise waffles, however I hope I can help find us some awesome talks.

For quite a while I wanted to bring some [dev days love](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31942/bring-the-devdays-love-to-the-forsaken-continent-island-australia) Down Under.

Comment: +1 Nice one Waffles.  Glad you man'd up and nominated yourself.  You were kind of the obvious choice, being the only Antipodean (I think) on the SO books : )

Comment: Hells yeah, mate! Win!

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't mind helping out.

I'm [Alex from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31671/alex).

I'm currently living in Queensland, but intend to be in either Melbourne or Sydney by then.

Not sure if all my active tags would suit (*cough* PHP) but everyone likes to hear about JavaScript (or jQuery), right? ;)

Now that [nickf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9021/nickf) and [cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18393/cletus) have left our shores, I'm the third highest repped Australian on Stack Overflow, if that counts.

Answer (score 4):

I would be happy to help out picking & organizing content for the dev days.

I am [reasonably active](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73488/redbluething) in a handful of tags. I mostly do [mobile development](http://www.tingofamily.com), dabble in [amateurish web development](http://www.cannonade.net/dev) and revel in my [inadequate design skills](http://www.cannonade.net/blog.php?tag=Art?).

I am active in the [Sydney GTUG](http://www.sydney-gtug.org/) and have a few contacts that might be useful for setting up speakers.

Answer (score 2):

I'd nominate myself for this in Sydney

Currently I have ~2200 reputation, all related to .NET and Web. I also have attended and check different web and Rials groups, etc.. so, might be one one part of an overall balance in choosing / weighing topics that can be interesting to various SO audience.

I also work as a consultant with few internal communities and ALT.NET ones that have exposure to different kinds of clients and might give some useful insights when asked.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/146656/mohamed-meligy

Not sure if it'll still be OK if I'm interested joining the curriculum committee and in delivering talks as well?

Answer (score 2):

I'm happy to help with organization if it ends up in Sydney. People seemed to think I did a decent job picking up the pieces at the Sydney Stack Exchange meetup. I'm also happy to talk about applications of the Philosophy of Data to IT and requirements, various RPG subjects, or the Social Construction of technology and why we should care.

Comment: a big +1 your organisational skills are second to none.

Comment: Well, I didn't exactly organize anything beforehand. But thanks for the +1 on my ad-hoc organization.

Answer (score 0):

+1 Sydney, because I work and live there :), the Stack exchange meetup held at Google in Pyrmont a couple months back worked out quite well... though at first it didn't have a clear set of goals to achieve, (I think Brians ad-hoc organization skills ^ saved it luckily) beyond talking shop and eating some food before heading to the PBH pub.

I'm happy to help in some way, if it's in the Sydney region.